# Sharing link for my website

Tags: php, web, share

I wish to have a sharing bar like in this page. http://www.templatebasics.com/wt00784bl/

How to make a sharing tab like this ?

I found that shareaholic is available only for blogs ? So, can I implement it on my website ??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo - Integrate SexyBookmarks into your Personal page with JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>

                        <center style="margin-top: 40px; color: silver;">
<div style="width: 600px;">
<p class="sexy-bookmarks-content" style="font-size: 22px; color: #000000;">Integrate SexyBookmarks into your Personal page with JavaScript</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.javascriptbank.com/javascript/article/Integrate_SexyBookmarks_into_your_Personal_page_with_JavaScript/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.javascriptbank.com/javascript/article/Integrate_SexyBookmarks_into_your_Personal_page_with_JavaScript/sexy-bookmarks-public.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.javascriptbank.com/javascript/article/Integrate_SexyBookmarks_into_your_Personal_page_with_JavaScript/sexy-bookmarks-style.css" media="screen" />
                        <div class="sexy-bookmarks sexy-bookmarks-expand sexy-bookmarks-center sexy-bookmarks-bg-sexy">
                            <ul class="socials">
                                <li class="sexy-twittley"><a href="http://twittley.com/submit/" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Submit this to Twittley">Submit this to Twittley</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-digg"><a href="http://digg.com/submit" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Digg this!">Digg this!</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/home" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Tweet This!">Tweet This!</a></li>

                                <li class="sexy-scriptstyle"><a href="http://scriptandstyle.com/submit" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Submit this to Script &amp; Style">Submit this to Script &amp; Style</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-reddit"><a href="http://reddit.com/submit" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Share this on Reddit">Share this on Reddit</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-delicious"><a href="http://del.icio.us/post" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Share this on del.icio.us">Share this on del.icio.us</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-stumbleupon"><a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Stumble upon something good? Share it on StumbleUpon">Stumble upon something good? Share it on StumbleUpon</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-mixx"><a href="http://www.mixx.com/submit" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Share this on Mixx">Share this on Mixx</a></li>

                                <li class="sexy-technorati"><a href="http://technorati.com/faves" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Share this on Technorati">Share this on Technorati</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-blinklist"><a href="http://www.blinklist.com/index.php" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Share this on Blinklist">Share this on Blinklist</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-diigo"><a href="http://www.diigo.com/post">Post this on Diigo</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-yahoobuzz"><a href="http://buzz.yahoo.com/submit/" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Buzz up!">Buzz up!</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-myspace"><a href="http://www.myspace.com/Modules/PostTo/Pages/" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Post this to MySpace">Post this to MySpace</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Share this on Facebook">Share this on Facebook</a></li>

                                <li class="sexy-designfloat"><a href="http://www.designfloat.com/submit.php" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Submit this to DesignFloat">Submit this to DesignFloat</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-devmarks"><a href="http://devmarks.com/index.php" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Share this on Devmarks">Share this on Devmarks</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-newsvine"><a href="http://www.newsvine.com/_tools/seed&amp;save" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Seed this on Newsvine">Seed this on Newsvine</a></li>
                                <li class="sexy-google"><a href="http://www.google.com/bookmarks/mark" rel="nofollow" class="external" title="Add this to Google Bookmarks">Add this to Google Bookmarks</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
</div><i>Live demo by <a href="http://www.javascriptbank.com">JavaScriptBank.com</a></i></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Tutorial: 
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/integrate-sexybookmarks-html-page-javascript/

Live Demo:
http://www.javascriptbank.com/javascript/article/Integrate_SexyBookmarks_into_your_Personal_page_with_JavaScript/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Apture](http://www.apture.com/), seems to provide the same service :-) Picture of the bar [here](http://landscapephotographymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/apture-bar.png).